# Rails 5.2.4: key must be 32 bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have updated my rails app to Ruby 2.4.9p362 and rails 5.2.4. This code was working before the update:

```
require 'digest'
require 'base64'

class EncryptionService
  def self.generateVerificationEmailToken(user)
    salt  = SecureRandom.random_bytes(64) 
    key = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(Yanpy::RESET_PASSWORD_KEY).generate_key(salt)
    cipher = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(key)
    encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt_and_sign(user.email) # This line returns error
    token = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(salt) + encrypted_data 
    ...
```

But after upgrade I get next error:

```
key must be 32 bytes
  70295339497960       /Users/Rober/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:169:in `key='
  70295339497960       /Users/Rober/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:169:in `_encrypt'
  70295339497960       /Users/Rober/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:151:in `encrypt_and_sign'
```

I have read other posts that say this is a bug that is fixed in rails 4.2. but my version is later.

Comment: Try `... Yanpy::RESET_PASSWORD_KEY).generate_key(salt, 32)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Pavel suggested, I actually solved it with:

```
len   = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len
    salt  = SecureRandom.random_bytes(len)
    key   = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(Yanpy::RESET_PASSWORD_KEY).generate_key(salt, len)
```

Comment: but on decryption it returns token invalid, is there any fix for the same??